# Is there a standard way to create a "view" of a list in python with an element excluded?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a huge list and a function that expects a list as an argument. This function does not modify the list in any way.
I want to pass this list to the function, but with an element excluded.
Removing the element would require me to copy the entire list without the element I want to exclude, which is obviously inefficient, and also unnecessary, since the function only views the elements of the list.

One way is to create a custom view class that implements `__len__`, `__getitem__`, `__iter__` and other collections' methods and "excludes" the element from the list, by returning `len-1` in `__len__` and returning `n+1`th element instead of `n`th if `n` is greater or equal to the "excluded" element index.

My question, is there any standard way to do that? Is there any such view class in the python's standard library? I will also consider external libraries if there are any. Just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such tool in the standard library.

Comment: If the function would accept an iterator this could be done easily.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, no, the function accepts a list-like collection, with at least `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods implemented

Comment: There's nothing efficient for doing this with iterators in the standard library either, as far as I'm aware. (`itertools.chain`-ing two `itertools.islice`s isn't efficient - the second `islice` would have to waste a lot of time iterating through elements it's going to ignore. `islice` has no fast path for random-access sequences.)

Comment: The list to exclude is always known by index, not by value? What's the use case for this?

Comment: Does it have to be a list? If you used numpy arrays, you could use views for the subarrays before and after the omitted element.

Comment: @Barmar, the element to exclude is known by its index (the element is found by some algorithm first). There could be a lot of use cases. In my case, it's some math in Nelder–Mead method, having points of the simplex, I need to compute the centroid of all points except the worst point. It has to be a one list-compatible argument, but not two (for list before and after omitted element).

Comment: @user2357112 The iterator solution would be easy to write and is at least memory-efficient. But of course you are right.